# Regex capitalise first character after colon

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects called userRoles.

```
const userRoles = [
  {
    "name": "Country: FR",
    "description": "Used for france contents"
  }
  {
    "name": "Country: UK",
    "description": "Used for UK contents"
  }
]
```

I've created a function to map over this with Regex expression to locate the Colon and remove it.

```
  const getUserRole = () => {
    const sanitizedRoles = userRoles.map(role => {
      const cleanRole = role.name.toLowerCase().replace(/:\s*/g, "")

      return cleanRole; // Outputs `['countryfr', 'countryuk']`
    })
  }
```

Now I would like to change the first character after the colon to be capitalised so the output would be like this `['countryFr', 'countryUk']`

Comment: Please search before posting ([on-site](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+regex+capitalize) or with [a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+regex+capitalize+site%3Astackoverflow.com) or both). More about searching on-site [here](/help/searching).

Comment: do you really need a regex for this?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. Split would work fine. Here's what I would do (doesn't actually answer the question so I'll add as a comment).
`const [roleName, roleCode] = role.name.split(': ');`
`const cleanRole = roleName.toLowerCase() + roleCode.substr(0, 1) + roleCode.substr(1).toLowerCase();`